# show success message on same page after adding recording without reloadin the site in cakephp 2.x

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I want to add a show sucess message using :-
                session->flash(); ?> in view and added the message in controller :-
                Session->setFlash("Record has been saved successfully."); ?>

But I donot want to reload the whole page.
I am just inserting the new record using ajax.. and refreshing the div having list of all record.
       session->flash(); ?> this works if i reload the whole page. 
how can I show message once the record is saved using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions (i recommend the first one):

1. Create AJAX method in controller that return 200 code with JSON/HTML record's data or any other error code if sth goes wrong. Then in js do:

   ```
   $.ajax({ ... }).done(function( data ) {
       // Success, show the record and message
       $('#flash').text('Success!').show();
       // ...
   }).error( function() {
       // Error
       $('#flash').text('Error!').show();
   });
   ```
2. Refresh the records list by calling ajax method and return not only the view with list of all records, but also a flash message (in the same view). Then show it or [move](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) using javascript.